# Determinant of matrix that contains a column of same numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Given $4\times 4$ matrix:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
x &  x+a&  0& 1\\ 
 x+a&  x&  a& 1\\ 
 0&  a&  x& 1\\ 
 1&  -1&  1& 1
\end{vmatrix}=x+a$$

Is it safe to assume that the determinant equals $0$ because there is a column than contains the same numbers(most right) and using Gaussian elimination technique I can turn it into zeroes and then the determinant is $0$. Is it correct?

Comment: What is the determinant of $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & a \\ 1 & b \end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Depends on the number. A column of zero elements would zero the determinant. Otherwise the four columns vectors might (but must not) be linear independent, which would give a non-zero determinant.

Comment: The determinant is neither zero nor $x+a$. You should fix or reword the question.

Comment: @copper.hat sorry to dissapoint you this is the determinant. Our teacher solved it today in class

Comment: You might want to check again that your question is the one that your teacher solved.

Comment: Just as an experiment, try setting $x=a=1$ and evaluate the determinant. You will get $-4$. If you use the expression above you will get $2$. Your turn...

Comment: This isn't your main question, but you should clarify whether this was presented as "This is true for all $x$" or "Simplify the determinant and then solve for $x$". The difference can affect how people approach the problem.

Comment: I am still devastated by the disappointment. Look at http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant+of+%7B%7Bx,x%2Ba,0,1%7D,%7Bx%2Ba,x,a,1%7D,%7B0,a,x,1%7D,%7B1,-1,1,1%7D%7D

Answer (score 1):

No. Try to think about what happens if you were to carry out the Gaussian elimination you propose. You can turn all but one of the $1$s into a $0$, but your proposed last step wouldn't work -- you can't subtract a row from itself when doing Gaussian elimination.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not correct, unless that “same number” is $0$. For instance$$\begin{vmatrix}1&0&0&\ldots&0&a\\0&1&0&\ldots&0&a\\0&0&1&\ldots&0&a\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\cdots&1&a\\0&0&0&\cdots&0&a\end{vmatrix}=a.$$

Answer (score 0):

Fix $a$ and let $p$ be the value of the determinant which is a polynomial in $x$. Note that $p(0) = p(-a) = 0$ and so $x(x+a)$ must divide $p$. Also note that $p$ has degree 2.

A little more grind shows that $p(a)=-2(1+a)^2$ from which we conclude that $p(x) = -2(1+a)x(x+a)$.

Alternatively, let [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant%20of%20%7B%7Bx,x%2Ba,0,1%7D,%7Bx%2Ba,x,a,1%7D,%7B0,a,x,1%7D,%7B1,-1,1,1%7D%7D) do the work.

Comment: I can't quickly see that $p$ has degrees 2; there's an $x^3$ term along the main diagonal if you evaluate it simple-mindedly. Can you add some more details on that point?

Comment: @JonathanZ: Originally I thought the same. The only way to get a power of 3 is for the $\det$ expansion to go through the $x$ at the $3,3$ element of matrix. However, the $x^2$ terms from the $(1-2),(1-2)$ part of the matrix cancel, leaving only $x^2$ terms in the final expansion.

Comment: Okay, I see it now, but I don't think it's obvious and could use a little more detail (like your comment provides).